# Nginx url rewriting - skip a portion of a path

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

**Updated**

Hi so I don't really understand how nginx's rewriting works all that well.
I want to be able to do a rewrite as follows:

/hosting/(some company name)/(web template name)/

and rewrite it to something like this:

/templates/(template name)/

where the company name would be omitted (that information is only needed by the client-side).

What I have currently is this:

```
server {
    listen    80 default_server;
    listen    [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root      /usr/local/www/html;

    location ~ ^/hosting {
        rewrite ^/hosting/([^/]+)/(.*) /templates/$2 last;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

I no longer get an error, but now the page does a full redirect, when I want it to keep the current url

My folder structure from the root is as follows:

```
html
-- templates
----- test
-------- index.html
-- 40x.html
-- 50x.html
```

What should I change to make this work as intended?

Comment: change the error_log level to info/debug to see at least rewrite logs

Comment: I saw what my problem was, I didn't have a break or last on my rewrite rule.  It also worked when I moved it inside a /hosting location block.  The only problem Im having now, is that the rewrite is also changing the external url in the browser, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the output of your error.log?

Your config looks valid to me